# Recognizing only a specific voice

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have made a speech recognition algorithm that converts speech to text in python using pocketsphinx. What I would like to know is if it is possible to make a speech recognition system that would only recognize my voice and nobody else. How can I do this?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible yet, additional work on cmusphinx is required. If you simply want hotword detection, you can probably consider personal models in https://github.com/kitt-ai/snowboy.